# Apache Spark using Java group rows based on condition and do calculation

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have Dataset like

[image]

I want to filter this data based on following points:

1) group data for same contentId, userId and viewCount.

2) get calculation done on the videoTime for beforeSeek and seek event (they will always come in pair of beforeSeek and seek). So need to subtract beforeSeek time from next seek Time.

Im using Java and Apache Spark.

Desired OutPut may look like

[image]

Comment: how do you calculate calTime?

Comment: it can be sum of one beforeseek and seek pair which are in consecutive rows

Comment: i din get ur computation logic. it would be good to give some sort of pseudo code for calculation alone